# Update UI from code behind in real time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created a socket listener, and I need to display a div (keep it hidden, then make it visible), when the server detects a certain socket data.

I've tried to use a thread, but it doesn't update the UI in realtime, only if the page is reloaded or if you do a post back.
Here is an example of what I want to do, in this case I only want to update a textbox with codebehind data, I would like to do it without ajax, javascript or jQuery, if possible.
**Code Behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(TestThread);
            t.Start();
        }

        private void TestThread()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000000; i++)
            {
                myTextbox.Text += "1";
            }
        }
```

**Webpage:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="myPanel" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="myTextbox" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

For real-time web functionality check out :

[SignalR](http://signalr.net/)

In a web enviornment, there is no way for the server side to reach out for the client except in the request-response scenario, where the client has to send a request to the server side, the server side handles the request and replies with a response.

EDIT :

SignalR uses the best available technique, websockets when available, if not, AJAX long polling technique in which the client polls(sends a request) to the server, and the server replies only when a certain change to the observed data happens, else SignalR tries repetitve AJAX requests, polling the server over and over until the server replies with the change on the observed data (Worst scenario !).

Also, HTML 5 contains web-sockets, i don't have enough information about it, but it maybe interesting to check out.

Comment: Actually afaik SignalR chooses the best available technique, and tries web sockets, long polling, and repetitive ajax requests

Comment: @Andrei technically when web sockets are not available, long polling is the best choice. Thanks for pointing out that it chooses out the best available technique, i thought it only used long-polling

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to do is change the UI (modify client components) from server code (code behind) in asp.net when the server already sent the data to the client.

you have to use client side scripting/coding.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible without using ajax or JavaScript.
ASP.NET is only responsible for generating the html that is sent from your web-server to the client.  Once that html is rendered in the browser, the only way to update the html is via JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You [can do a Partial Render in WebForms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax) using their AJAX handler without having to write jQuery by enabling a `partialRenderingEnabled` attribute in the `ScriptManager` tag. There's no way to do this without scripting or AJAX, the content has to get back to the server to run your code-behind somehow, but at least this way you don't have to write any JavaScript yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Threads gets aborted as soon as the page unloads, so this is not possibler you way, sorry.

Your approach could be using AJAX to poll the status from the server on regular intervals. Server on the other hand, will reply according to change in data.

in your ASP.NET Page, add the following script

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     function poll()
     {
       var ajax;
       if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
           ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
       else
           ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

       url = "yourPageOrHandler.aspx";

       ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
       {
          if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200)
          {
             // success
             var receivedText = ajax.responseText;
          }
          else
          {
             // error, do the needful
          }
       }

       ajax.open("GET", url, true);        
       ajax.send();

       setTimeout("poll()", 1000); //polls every 1 second, you can change the duration here.
     }
  </script>
</head>
```

Start the polling before page finishes

```
<body>
   .
   .
   .
   .
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     poll();
  </script>
</body>
```

Alternatively, you can use the ASP.NET AJAX controls, but that will be heavier compared to JavaScript AJAX.

---

*Glad to help! Please remember to accept the answer if you found it helpful.*

Answer (score 1):

With minimal JavaScript you could utilise Server Sent Events for simplex data (from server to client) It doesn't have the overhead of Websockets which has a bit of cost in terms of establishing a connection.  However I don't think all browsers are supported but there might be polyfill available for it (library to provide functionality in absence of native support) 
Checkout:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/